# Using Rhino Mocks to assert that a method was called after a given period of time

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Does anyone know if it's possible to use Rhino Mocks to check if a method was called within  a given period of time?

Here's the code I want to write a unit test for:

```
while (true)
    if (TimeoutErrorStopwatch.IsRunning && 
        TimeoutErrorStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > timeoutErrorTime)
    {
        someClass.HandleError();
    }
    else
        Thread.Sleep(10);
```

I want to write a unit test that ensures that the error is caught by checking whether the HandleError method was called. This loop is running on its own background thread, so I'm wondering if there's a way to assert that the method was called with a constraint to keep checking and assert that the method is called within a given time. Something to the effect of:

```
someClass.AssertWasCalled(s => s.HandleError()).Within(10);
```

My current work-around is I simply call `Thread.Sleep(10)` and then use `AssertWasCalled`, but I'm wondering if something like this is supported in Rhino Mocks.

Thanks!

------ EDIT ------

In light of the comment, I wrote an extension method that checks to see if the method has been called until the given time limit has been reached, sleeping in between failed calls. I have actually already mocked the timers (in the real application, the timeout is set to 30 minutes whereas in my test I have set mock values of 100 milliseconds or less). I thought I would post my extension in case anyone stumbles upon this post.

```
public static void AssertWasCalledWithin<T>(this T stub, Action<T> action, long milliseconds)
    {
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var e = new Exception();
        while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds <= milliseconds)
            try
            {
                stub.AssertWasCalled(action);
                return;
            }
            catch (ExpectationViolationException exc)
            {
                e = exc;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

        throw new ExpectationViolationException(
            string.Format(
                "The following expectation was not met within the " +
                "given time limit of {0} milliseconds: {1}",
                milliseconds, e.Message));
    }
```

Comment: Other than actually sleeping in the test, the standard way to test these things is to mock the timing source itself.

Comment: If everything is under your control consider adding a time interface and control that. When you can control the passage of time through an interface you remove that dependency and the test is less brittle.

Answer (score 2):

I use ManualResetEvent for such types of tests in combination with WhenCalled extension method:

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

...

someClassMock.Stub(sc => sc.HandleError()).WhenCalled(invocation => mre.Set());

...

testedClass.TestedMethod(); // call your real code using someClassMock

...

mre.WaitOne(timeoutErrorTime);

someClassMock.AssertWasCalled(sc => sc.HandleError());
```

Modify the example as you need. Do not forget that ManualResetEvent is diposable. I use test initialize and test complete methods to instantiate and dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your testing needs you may want to introduce an interface to time. This may not be helpful if you can not rewrite the consumer of time.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Rhino.Mocks;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow_namespace
{
    public interface IDateTime
    {
        DateTime Now();
    }

    public class DateTimeAdapter : IDateTime
    {
        public DateTime Now() { return DateTime.Now; }
    }

    public class Waiter
    {
        public static void WaitAnHour(IDateTime time)
        {
            //Incredibly wasteful - just to illustrate the point
            DateTime start = time.Now();
            DateTime end = start + TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            while (end < time.Now()) ;
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    class StackOverflow
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestingTimeout()
        {
            DateTime testtime = DateTime.Now;
            var time = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDateTime>();
            time.Stub(x => x.Now()).Do(new Func<DateTime>(() => { return testtime; }));
            var task = Task.Run(() => Waiter.WaitAnHour(time));
            Assert.IsFalse(task.IsCompleted, "Just Started");
            testtime = testtime.AddMinutes(60);
            task.Wait();
            Assert.IsTrue(task.IsCompleted, "60 Minutes Later");
        }

    }
}
```